# Add javascript change trigger to Primefaces selectonemenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a quite complex form built with PrimeFaces 4.0 and i want to add some client-side jQuery/Javascript-Code which should be triggered if the value of any of the form input fields changes.

For `<p:inputText>` and `<p:selectBooleanCheckbox>` I can register an event handler with `$(this).change(handler);`

How can I register this handler for a `<p:selectonemenu>`? Registering the handler on the Element itself or the embedded `_input`-Field doesn't trigger the handler when I change the value.

Note: I do not want to set the handler directly on the Primefaces-Tag, but dynamically via jQuery.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:
Primefaces creates a seperate panel for displaying the options which gets displayed if the user clicks on the `<p:selectonemenu>`. The id of this panel is the id of the selectonemenu + "_panel". As it is a panel and not an input of any kind `click()` must be used instead of `change()`
Example:

```
$(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId($(this).attr('id')+"_panel")).click(handler);
```

Obviously, in the handler you have to switch back to the menu with something like this:

```
if($(this).attr('id').endsWith('_panel')){
                widget =  $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId($(this).attr('id').substring(0,$(this).attr('id').length - '_panel'.length)));
```